# Angular material issue with latest version of angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create navbar with angular material. So I begin with few setups:

1) I installed angular materials with npm
2) I configured theming in style.css as below:

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
@import '~https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';
```

3) I linked angular material themes to index.html as below:

```
<link href="../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

For more information about my environment take a look at my angular.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "admin-portal": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "targets": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/admin-portal",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "admin-portal:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "admin-portal:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "admin-portal:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "admin-portal-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "targets": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "admin-portal:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "admin-portal:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "admin-portal"
}
```

But when run ng serve, i get this error as mentioned below:

> ```
>  ERROR in ./src/styles.css (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./src/styles.css)
>     Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js):
>     Error: Can't resolve 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons' in
> ```
>
> 'C:\Angular Projects\admin-portal\src'
>               at doResolve (C:\Angular Projects\admin-portal\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:180:19)
>               at hook.callAsync (C:\Angular Projects\admin-portal\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5)
>               at _fn0 (eval at create (C:\Angular Projects\admin-portal\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10),
>   :15:1)
>               at resolver.doResolve (C:\Angular Projects\admin-portal\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\UnsafeCachePlugin.js:37:5)
>               at hook.callAsync (C:\Angular Projects\admin-portal\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5)
>               at _fn0 (eval at create (C:\Angular Projects\admin-portal\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10),
>   :15:1)
>               at hook.callAsync (C:\Angular Projects\admin-portal\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5)
>               at _fn0 (eval at create (C:\Angular Projects\admin-portal\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10),
>   :12:1)
>               at resolver.doResolve (C:\Angular Projects\admin-portal\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:42:38)
>               at hook.callAsync (C:\Angular Projects\admin-portal\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5)
>               at _fn5 (eval at create (C:\Angular Projects\admin-portal\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10),
>   :57:1)
>               at resolver.doResolve (C:\Angular Projects\admin-portal\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\ModuleKindPlugin.js:23:37)
>               at hook.callAsync (C:\Angular Projects\admin-portal\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5)
>               at _fn0 (eval at create (C:\Angular Projects\admin-portal\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10),
>   :15:1)
>               at hook.callAsync (C:\Angular Projects\admin-portal\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5)
>               at _fn1 (eval at create (C:\Angular Projects\admin-portal\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10),
>   :24:1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it's not working is because you specified that the path is local when you're supposed to use the `url` function. (Also, you're specifying themes and fonts both times, you're supposed to be specifying them either in your `index.html` file **OR** your `styles.css` file, **NOT** in both of the files).

You can either use the following configuration or the other one:

1. All imports in `styles.css`:

   ```css
   @import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');
   ```
2. All imports in `index.html`:

   ```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css">
   ```

Comment: I followed steps as mentionned in [official docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) but they doesn't specify that i should import Material and icons of google apis fonts in style.css .Thanks for your help